# How old are these Bridgestone B250 tyres?

Tags: tires

A dealership fitted these tyres at the front of my (UK) Honda Jazz in December 2016.

A independent mechanic has shown me a "1093" code on the tyre, said that means they date from October 1993 (!), and perhaps I was sold old stock.

But I wonder if the mechanic has misread the code.

I can see these codes (among other more generic looking safety markings) on the outside of the tyre:

```
E4 023873 S1WR1 59716 | B250AZ
MADE IN ITALY
175/65R15 84T
TUBELESS | STEEL BELTED RADIAL
E3 02 | 1093
9CYU M3Y
BRIDGESTONE B250
```

I don't see a DOT code, and I can't seem to interpret these markings using any diagrams I've found on the Internet so far.

I've tried to have a look on the inside of the tyre for other markings, but my access is limited, and the details I can make out seem the same as above.

Were these really manufactured in 1993?

[image: Whole tyre]

[image: Detail 1]

[image: Detail 2]

[image: Detail 3]

Comment: Did you check both sides of the tire? It may be printed on the other side. From what I just read, tire manufacturers aren't exactly required to print it on both sides.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes, I tried, but my access is limited (it lives on the street, so I don't want to jack it up). My best attempt was doing a video recording (with on camera lighting), but it wasn't great. From what I could make out, the details on the inside were the same as the outside.

Comment: If it's any consolation, they didn't start putting a date stamp on them until 2000, which means the "93" does not indicate they were done in 93. I realize that is of little comfort. I'd bet the date stamp is on there somewhere, lol ... it's just being elusive.

Comment: I'd contact Bridgestone directly, they have a customer support team to answer questions like this. If it's any help those tires look in good condition, it's extremely unlikely those tires are that old.

Comment: @GdD Thanks! I've asked Bridgestone UK and I'll report back.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is in the US, since you mentioned DOT, however the 'Jazz' is called 'Fit' in the US. Anyway...

Tires manufactured before 2000 had a 3-digit date code: the first 2 digits for the week of the year, the last for the year.  For example, a tire manufactured in October 1993 would be marked (perhaps) '423'

Since 2000, the date codes have a 2-digit year.  The date code is the last 4 digits of the DOT tire identification number, which always starts with 'DOT'.  (The DOT marking is required for tires sold in the US)

That 'E3' marking is some kind of European approval.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention I'm in the UK. I've added that to the question. I mentioned DOT because that's what I've seen people explain on the web about tyre dates - I don't know if the UK / EU use a different system. Many thanks - I'm a bit reassured. Am still on the trail to figure out an actual date if I can.

Answer (score 1):

OP here again...

I managed to get a better look on the inside walls of the tyre, using a torch and a GoPro, with the video streaming to my phone to help me orient the camera.  Sadly, I didn't see `DOT` printed anywhere, and I was about to give up.

Finally though, I carefully compared the codes on the inside wall with those I'd noted for the outside, and noticed that the `9CYU M3Y` code on the outside was repeated, but with additional characters on the inside.

```
9CYU M3Y T 4216
```

[Bridgestone UK](https://www.bridgestone.co.uk/contact-us) have confirmed that those last 4 digits are the date of production code, meaning the 42nd week of 2016.

Thanks for the help, everyone!

[image: Code on inside of tyre]